# Way of thinking to solve my program problems

Tags: tkinter, time

[My steps to solve my program design problems](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ffblw.png)

In a simple way, I'm totally new to programming, just studied the essentials of Python,

I want -my self with your help- to design a program to do my daily routine in my company to save my time to do something else - Note: I don't want someone to do it for me but your help is much appreciated in your guidance and justifications -,

So I'm designing a program with user input screen to do the following:

1. I will write the task number.
2. The program should take the number and search in company tasks to find out who is the client and item number related to this task number.
3. If this info founded, the program will display it on the screen with a button to do the next step action if I need it.
4. the action is all related to log in to a website and get some info from this website.

the image is for my way of thinking to solve this problem, for the first step your feedback about the following is much appreciated :

- Is this program should be one Python file, or what I'm doing in dividing too many files is correct?
- from understanding the concept, your advice about the good module to use it is much appreciated, currently, I'm using the following:

  - tkinter
  - time
  - webbot

Answer (score 0):

Since this seems to be a small program, it will be enough with one python file. However, the company data should be in an other file.

Tkinter is good for simple GUIs.

If you need to use the system time, by all means use time.

I have little experience with accessing the web with Python. I have used `urllib` for getting webpages but I don't really know how much you can do with this module. If you want to parse HTML there is `html.parser`. All in the standard library.

Comment: Many thanks for your reply,

One python file, thanks for this instruction, will try it.

The company data in another file, you mean I create a class and define all company tasks and items number, correct?

Tkinter is more than enough for me for the moment and really it looks nice.

urllib ?, is it doing like webbot ?, I want to login, fill data, clicks ...etc., 

html.parser, I will study to know this first, maybe i will need it

Comment: The company data in a separate file: I meant that you should have a separate source for the company data because it might change. If there is a new client you don't want to alter the Python program. The data could be a plain text file or a database for example. Urllib is used for fetching web resources. I'm not sure if you can also pass data to an url with it.